# Как создать два бина с одинаковым классом с помощью метода и закидывать их в определнные классы?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Всем привет, я хочу создать пару бинов в классе с разной конфигурацией то типу :

```
public class Clazz {

//класс у бина одинаковый Client, но внутри конфигурация разная 
//инициализируется через методы

@Bean(name="Bean1")
public Client1 (){}

@Bean(name = "Bean2")
public Clien2t (){}
}
```

И прокидывать какой то из них, который нужен в нужные классы c помощью конструкции

```
public class ClassForInjectBean1{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Bean1")
@NotNull 
Client client
....
}

public class ClassForInjectBean2{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Bean2")
@NotNull 
Client client
....
}
```

На самом деле я пробовал в классах, куда надо инжектить и вариант типа :

```
@Resource(name = "Bean2")
@NotNull 
Client client
```

и пробовал

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Bean2")
```

Но он не понимает, какой из двух бинов прокидывать

Ошибка : 
Parameter 1 of constructor in ClassForInjectBean1 required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - Bean1 : defined by method 'Client1' in class path resource...
    - Bean1: defined by method ''Client1' in class path resource...
Почему не получается прокинуть ?

Я в курсе, что можно сделать интерфейс, имплиментить его и закидывать компонеты, как здесь 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation , но хотелось бы с помощью метода, тогда не надо плодить кучу сущностей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все таки лучше было бы реализовать интерфейс. Не понятно, `Clazz` это `@Configuration` или `@Component`? Если это компонент, то документация не рекомендует так делать, в таком случае вы получите `lite @Bean`. Лучше сделать так:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {
   @Bean("client1")
   public Client client1() {
      var client = new Client();
      client.setSomeFieldName(1);
      client.setSomeFieldName(2);
      client.setSomeFieldName(3);
      client.setSomeFieldName(4);

      return client;
   }

   @Bean("client2")
   public Client client2() {
      var client = new Client();
      client.setSomeFieldName(5);
      client.setSomeFieldName(6);
      client.setSomeFieldName(7);
      client.setSomeFieldName(8);

      return client;
  }
}
```